# PHP ZipArchive: how to fix inaccurate file dates?

Tags: php, datetime, php-ziparchive

I have a php (7.0.33) script that zips a whole web directory, complete with sub-folders & files.
After downloading and extracting such an archive, I noticed that the file dates from within the zip are all shifted by 2 hours (and 1 second) compared with the respective file dates from the server, which happens to be my time zone's offset (UTC/GMT +2 hours).

I need the dates to be accurate.

So it looks like a time zone issue, but I cannot see how I could fix it. I have read that ZipArchive doesn't support timezone settings...?

So I thought I might use the setMtimeIndex() method from ZipArchive:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setmtimeindex.php
to set proper file dates while zipping them.
But the server states that the method is undefined.
The documentation specifies that the method is available starting from Libzip ≥ 1.0.0.
My server has Libzip 1.1.2, so...?

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: It also says that you need `PECL zip >= 1.16.0`, so maybe it is that?

Comment: The manual page states PHP >= 8.0.0 also this could be OS related. Windows and Linux for example have different ways of offsetting the time

Comment: _"I need the dates to be accurate."_ would that be without the additional second or do you mean the two hours difference? Mind that the Zip format time information is w/o timezones. // There is also [Phar::ZIP with timestamps](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/10766) and if constraints keep you on 7.0.33 and you can't update the zip extension for the functionality you need, Debian has a PHP package which _may_ offer you the functionality: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/php-pclzip (but I can't say which PHP versions it supports, use older Debian releases probably).